# @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/stack read whole stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

OK, so I have my App.js

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Pokus" component={PokusScreen} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>;
```

Then in my Home component, I redirect to the Main component.

I pass navigation like this:

```
export default function Home({ navigation })
```

My question is: Can I now read stack?

Can I say something like: `navigation.ReadStack()`?

What I want to see?:I want to see something like `{ { name: "Home", index: 0 }, { name: "Main", index: 1 }  }`

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: My code in Main component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { last_activity_token, UpdateActivity } from '../Models/activityModel';
import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function Main({ navigation }) {
  //constanty -- constants
  const [activity, setActivity] = useState(new last_activity_token());

  const Pokus = () => {
    const state = useNavigationState(state => state);
    alert(JSON.stringify(state.routes))
  }

  //Load event
  React.useEffect(() => {
    activity.page.name = "Main";
    UpdateActivity(activity);
  });

  //vzhled stránky -- design of page 
  return (
      <View style={styles.layout}>
        <Text>Main</Text>
        <View style={styles.MainContent}>
          <Text>Tady se to vše bude odehrávat</Text>
          <Button onPress={Pokus}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
}

//css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    layout: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    MainContent: {
      marginTop: 20
    }
});
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by reading Stack ?
there are different methods in React navigation for different purposes.

Comment: If you want to read all the screen, then store all screen name and components in an array and use it in Stack.Navigator to render screens using map

Comment: What I am trying to achive is: Read Stack. I am trying to do: Read stack -> store it in token -> then load stack from token. I know how to store token and I know how to load stack from token. What I dont know is how to read stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current state by using the useNavigationState hook like below

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/

```
import {useNavigationState} from '@react-navigation/native';

const state = useNavigationState((state) => state);

alert(JSON.stringify(state.routes));
```

This will give an output of the screen in the route

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See URL for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Ok you are using a class component ? check this way of passing as a prop https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/#using-with-class-component

Comment: put const state = useNavigationState(state => state); outside the Pokus function it should work then